# Vanilla Javascript show tab and hide others

Tags: javascript, tabs

right now im recreating a Bootstrap element "Toggleable / Dynamic Tabs" (you can find it there - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navs.asp) but I cant get my content running. The "tabs" are working as intented but I don't know how to get them to show content after click how I wanted. I want them to show "linked" div when clicked and hide divs linked to the other buttons. Just like the bootstrap element. Thank you very much!

I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Darlington/9kjst3rp/8

```js
let tabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.subnavBtn'));

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  tabs.forEach(node => {
    node.classList.remove('active-btn');
  });
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active-btn');

}

tabs.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
});
```

```css
.subnavDiv {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.active-btn {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="subnav">
 <button class="subnavBtn">
   Button 1
 </button>

 <button class="subnavBtn">
   Button 2
 </button>

 <button class="subnavBtn">
   Button 3
 </button>
</nav>

<!-- DIVS I WANT TO SHOW -->

<div class="subnavDiv active">
Content 1
</div>

<div class="subnavDiv">
Content 2
</div>

<div class="subnavDiv">
Content 3
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to be a basic problem I guess there is already existing solutions here. Basically you can add Id like "tab-1" and "contentTab-1" to query the corresponding tabContent or you can name an attribute as data-tab-content="1" as an option of your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maheer Ali's answer is fine, here's an alternative using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to specify which tab is associated with each button:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.subnavBtn');
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.subnavDiv');

const handleClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Buttons
  buttons.forEach(node => node.classList.remove('active-btn'));
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active-btn');
  
  // Divs (tabs)
  divs.forEach(node => node.classList.remove('active'));
  [...divs].filter(div => div.dataset.tab === e.currentTarget.dataset.tab)[0].classList.add('active');
}

buttons.forEach(node => node.addEventListener('click', handleClick));
```

```css
.subnavDiv { display: none; }
.active { display: block; }
.active-btn { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<nav class="subnav">
 <button class="subnavBtn active-btn" data-tab="1">Button 1</button>
 <button class="subnavBtn" data-tab="2">Button 2</button>
 <button class="subnavBtn" data-tab="3">Button 3</button>
</nav>

<div class="subnavDiv active" data-tab="1">Content 1</div>
<div class="subnavDiv" data-tab="2">Content 2</div>
<div class="subnavDiv" data-tab="3">Content 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in following steps

- Store all the divs(contents) in a array in global scope
- Pass the second variable `btn` for `handleClick`
- In the `forEach()` send the element of current index to `handleClick` as second parameter
- Inside the `handleClick` remove `active` class from all the divs
- At last add the `active` class the to `btn`(second parameter of function)

```js
let tabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.subnavBtn'));
let contents = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.subnavDiv'));


const handleClick = (e,btn) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  tabs.forEach(node => {
    node.classList.remove('active-btn');
  });
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active-btn');
  contents.forEach(x => x.classList.remove('active'))
  btn.classList.add('active');

}

tabs.forEach((node,i) => {
  node.addEventListener('click',(e) => handleClick(e,contents[i]))
});
```

```css
.subnavDiv {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.active-btn {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="subnav">
 <button class="subnavBtn">
   Button 1
 </button>

 <button class="subnavBtn">
   Button 2
 </button>

 <button class="subnavBtn">
   Button 3
 </button>
</nav>

<!-- DIVS I WANT TO SHOW -->

<div class="subnavDiv active">
Content 1
</div>

<div class="subnavDiv">
Content 2
</div>

<div class="subnavDiv">
Content 3
</div>
```